# How can I find the man page for compress-cli?

Tags: command-line-interface, manpage, compress-images

I am trying to run the [cli](https://github.com/ShaunLWM/node-compress-image-cli) made for [compress](https://github.com/semiromid/compress-images),

`compress -i /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/jcb-image-optimization/src -o /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/jcb-image-optimization/dist/images`

But got back:

> compress: illegal option -- i usage: compress [-cfv] [-b bits] [file
>   ...]

I tried to find help or a man page...

```
compress --h
compress --help
compress man
```

But I get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output above is an error message for [compress](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=compress&sektion=1), a BSD general command that is already installed on your computer. You can view the man page for that program with `man compress`, or verify its location with `which compress`.

The [CLI's README](https://github.com/ShaunLWM/node-compress-image-cli) linked to above uses a Windows-style file hierarchy in its example. The author likely didn't encounter the `compress` namespace collision while writing the package.

To run this CLI, you'll need to find out where NPM installed the executable, and run it directly (e.g. `/path/to/your/bin/compress -i something -o something`).